# Cannot create Twitter app

Tags: java, api, twitter, web-applications

I wanted to create an application on https://apps.twitter.com and when I fill the form and submit it, there is an error:

`Error
You must add your mobile phone to your Twitter profile before creating an application. Please read https://support.twitter.com/articles/110250-adding-your-mobile-number-to-your-account-via-web for more information.`

The problem is, that I've already added my mobile phone. When I change to "Mobile phones" in Twitter they show my mobile number. So what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Make sure that the account you are currently logged on with contains your number.

Comment: As I wrote, it already contains my mobile number. So I guess there is a bug?

Comment: Do you need to confirm it or something?

Comment: Yes and as I mentioned, I habe fully added my phone number. There must be a bug with New twitter accounts. Can someone seriously help me?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem is solved. It was really a misconfiguration in their system. Thanks!